# Pass an exception up to the method

Tags: java, spring, exception

I've got a method which throws an exception itself and calls a method which catches another exception:

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    if (authenticated()) {
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                name, password, new ArrayList<>());
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

private boolean authenticated(){
    try {      
        thirdPartyClass.login();
        return true;
    } catch (ThirdPartyException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

`thirdPartyClass.login()` is from an api I don't own and it is a void method so all unsuccessful authentications must be catched.

`ThirdPartyException` exception gives a good explanation of what went wrong so I'd like to have it as my error message instead of:

```
No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
```

which comes from `AuthenticationException`

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something along these lines:

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
    throws AuthenticationException 
{
    try {
        thirdPartyClass.login();
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                name, password, new ArrayList<>());
    } catch (ThirdPartyException tpe) {
        throw new AuthenticationException(tpe.getMessage(), tpe);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `AuthenticationException` is an abstract class I was playing with `ProviderNotFoundException` (suggested by the original message: No AuthenticationProvider found) which accepts only message parameter. Switching to `AuthenticationServiceException` subclass which accepts 2nd Throwable parameter did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the function with this code:

```
private boolean authenticated(){
try {      
      thirdPartyClass.login();
      return true;
    } catch (ThirdPartyException e) {
         return false;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
         return false;
    }
}
```

If the `thirdPartyClass.login();` is handling the exception and printing error on console then you can only ignore the message, and consider that thirdParty function is telling you that username and password tokens are not valid ones.

Comment: That still gives me the message the AuthenticatoinException provides.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get message from `ThirdPartyException`? If so, then you can do something like:

```
private boolean authenticated() throws ThirdPartyException {  
   thirdPartyClass.login();
   return true;
}
```

if  not, then kindly explain it

### Updated

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
    throws AuthenticationException 
{
    try {
        authenticated();
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                name, password, new ArrayList<>());
    } catch (ThirdPartyException ex) {
        throw new AuthenticationException(ex.getMessage(), ex);//or any other child exception of AuthenticationException
    }
}
```

Comment: method `authenticate()` (simplified for clarity) comes from a custom implementation of spring's `AuthenticationProvider` class. All I need is to present a different exception than an `AuthenticatoinException` provides.

Comment: but compiler will not allow you throw any other exception other than AuthenticatoinException or any of its child exception

Comment: I was thinking of extending `AuthenticationException` and "combining" with `ThirdPartyException`. I don't know if it's feasible.

Comment: or catch the exception thrown by authenticated() in authenticate(), and then create and throw new AuthenticatoinException exception with message thrown by authenticated() method

Comment: "I was thinking of extending AuthenticationException and "combining" with ThirdPartyException"
in this case, you have to handle your custom exception till the end. So if you just want to get message thrown by authenticate(), then above method will work fine
"or catch the exception thrown by authenticated() in authenticate(), and then create and throw new AuthenticatoinException exception with message thrown by authenticated() method "

Comment: Something like that (not working): catch (ThirdPartyException e) {
            throw new ProviderNotFoundException(e.getMessage());
        }

Comment: why, what's the issue?? where you have included above line??

Comment: all these below exceptions extends AuthenticationException, so you can use anyone of the below exceptions.

AccountStatusException, ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException, AuthenticationCancelledException, AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException, AuthenticationServiceException, BadCredentialsException, InsufficientAuthenticationException, NonceExpiredException, PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException, ProviderNotFoundException, RememberMeAuthenticationException, SessionAuthenticationException, UsernameNotFoundException